# Colorbox fixed width and height

Tags: 7, views, media, javascript

Can't seem to achieve such setting, just like the one shown at:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/
"Group Photo One" link under "No Transition + fixed width and height (75% of screen size)"

How to achieve that in D7 using Colorbox on my Views list of images? Tried all options, all dynamic and it's impossible to browse because navigation arrows are jumping all over because of the different image styles.

Comment: if there is no optionf or it, then use css